# Laravel Artisan CLI safely stop daemon queue workers

Tags: php, laravel, queue, daemon, laravel-artisan

In order to process large numbers of jobs, I run a variable number of queue workers depending on howmuch work there is to complete. I don't want to run more workers than are necessary to complete the work that needs to be done in a time period that we deem appropriate.

At the moment, I start 5 daemon queue workers for testing purposes, however in production this number could be between 25 & 100 workers, possibly more. I understand that when deploying, I have to stop the queue workers by first placing the framework in maintenance mode by using `php artisan down`, because the `--daemon` flag causes the framework to only load when the worker starts up, hence new code would not take affect during the deploy until the worker restarts.

If i needed to stop the workers for some reason, I could put the application in maintenance mode using `php artisan down` which will cause the workers to die once they have finished processing their current job (if they are working one). However, there may be times where I want to kill the workers without putting the whole application in maintenance mode.

**Is there a safe way to stop the workers in a way where they will continue processing their current job and then die without placing the whole application in maintenance mode?**

**Essentially what I need is a `php artisan queue:stop`, which behaves like `php artisan queue:restart`, but does not restart the worker once the job is done.**

I was expecing there to be a like `php artisan queue:stop` command that would do this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Using `ps aux | grep php` I am able to get the process id's for the workers, and I could kill the processes that way, but I don't want to kill the process in the middle of it working on a job.

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone who finds this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060526/laravel-artisan-cli-safely-stop-daemon-queue-workers#comment48332831_30087630 has the answer. php artisan queue:restart will stop the workers. The "restart" name is misleading. The workers won't actually restart after they are stopped.

Comment: is correct. The "restart" only happens if you have something like Supervisor setup to monitor and automatically restart them once they quit. (Which is the typical setup.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've implemented something like this in our application - but it was not something that was built-in to Laravel itself. You would have to edit [this file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L92), by adding another condition to the if-block so that it would call the `stop` function. You can do this by either setting a static variable in the `Worker` class that gets changed whenever you run a custom command that you'll have to make (i.e. `php artisan queue:pause`) or by checking an atomic value somewhere (i.e. set it in some cache like redis, memcached, APC or even MySQL, though this would mean you'll have one MySQL query for every cycle of this while-loop) that you set using the same custom command.

Comment: Yah I was afraid I was going to have to do something like this. Will have to get redis or memcache setup, checking the flag is kind of a waste of a query, especially when its happening for every iteration in a loop, with 25 - 100 workers. Best answer I've got sofar, so +. Hopefully they add something like this in later versions.

Comment: Yeah, APC/redis/memcached would be the way to go, with APC being the best in this situation.

Answer (score 9):

When using the `--daemon` flag workers shouldn't quit when the queue is empty.

I think what you are looking for is [in the documentation for queues.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#daemon-queue-worker)

The `php artisan queue:restart` command will prompt the workers to restart after they are done their current job.

Comment: Correct, I do not want the workers to stop when the queue is empty. What I am looking to do is stop the queue workers on command, but to do it "safely", so that they do not stop in the middle of processing a job. `php artisan queue:restart`, unfortunately does not do what I need it to do. I am not looking to restart the workers, I am looking to stop them "safely". The documentation does not contain any information on stopping a queue worker, its merely mentions that you may have to do it "manually".

Comment: Essentially what I need is a `php artisan queue:stop`, which behaves like `php artisan queue:restart`, but does not restart the worker once the job is done.

Comment: Open a terminal with `php artisan queue:work --daemon` and run `php artisan queue:restart` in another terminal. The first terminal will actually just shut down after a while. It doesn't actually restart it, thats up to a seperate process like http://supervisord.org/ to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Since Laravel 5.5 there is an event called `Illuminate\Queue\Events\Looping` that gets fired from the `daemonShouldRun()` call inside the main worker loop of `Illuminate\Queue\Worker`. So if you setup a listener to do your *should process jobs* check, and return false then the queue worker(s) will stop until the check returns true. There's a sleep between the next time it checks it which you can customise by passing `--sleep <seconds>` to the queue:work command.

I'm currently using this technique during deployments to stop workers which run inside docker containers, as it's not so easy to run the suggested `queue:restart` on them without hacking around.

Answer (score 2):

my Laravel is 5.6.
you can (kill your pid)  don't worry lose your work
just load pcntl(extension) Laravel can listen to the signal and safe exit

show part source below(in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php):

```
protected function listenForSignals()
{
    pcntl_async_signals(true);

    pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, function () {
        $this->shouldQuit = true;
    });

    pcntl_signal(SIGUSR2, function () {
        $this->paused = true;
    });

    pcntl_signal(SIGCONT, function () {
        $this->paused = false;
    });
}
```

And my test below:

```
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
        pcntl_async_signals(true);

    pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, function () {
        echo 'SIGTERM';
    });

    pcntl_signal(SIGUSR2, function () {
        echo 'SIGUSR2';
    });

    pcntl_signal(SIGCONT, function () {
        echo 'SIGCONT';
    });
echo $i; 
sleep(1);
 }
```

you can try to kill it

Comment: Jup not underestimating the importance of the `pcntl` extension and making sure your kill signal isn't set to `SIGKILL` (Default on the official Docker PHP images) but rather `SIGTERM` fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

also -  if (something=something) ? app('queue.worker')->shouldQuit = 1;

works well

Its also really good for jobs that suck up ram as it kills off the process then your horizon or whatever will kick it back in.