# force stop persistent php laravel artisan command from code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, phirehose

I have my own custom Laravel artisan command which runs persistently. [It is a command to run Twitter Streaming API](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-process-tweets-in-real-time-with-laravel) using [phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose). This command won't stop unless I do CTRL+C from the CMD. How do I simulate this CTRL+C behavior from the code as well. Is there anyway I could do that in Laravel (5.1)... or PHP?

This the test code that I try

```
Route::get('/damned_command', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('my_own_custom_persistent_command');
});
```

Right now, the code won't stop. It's filling up my DB non-stop XD. The only way I could stop it right now from melting my machine is by destroying the Homestead vagrant :p

closest clue that I got: [Laravel Artisan CLI safely stop daemon queue workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060526/laravel-artisan-cli-safely-stop-daemon-queue-workers?rq=1),
but I'm still not so sure how it's gonna work

Comment: Wouldn't be more convenient to handle this in `my_own_custom_persistent_command`?

Comment: @khalidDabjan: well the thing is, my own custom command actually just calls the actual persistent method from phirehose (which is built for CLI only), I can do nothing bout it