# Laravel 5.6. Stop a worker AFTER job execution with supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, supervisord, laravel-queue

Is it possible to send a stop signal to the worker in such a way, that it will stop only AFTER processing the job.

Currently I have a job, that takes some time AND can't be interrupted, cause I have only one try/attempt.

Sometimes I need to stop workers to redeploy my code. Is there a way to stop Laravel's worker only after finishing current job and before starting a new one?

I'm using `supervisor` for restarting the queue workers.

Cause currently on each deploy I'm loosing 1 job and my client loses money :(

P.S.

This is NOT a duplicate of [Laravel Artisan CLI safely stop daemon queue workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060526/laravel-artisan-cli-safely-stop-daemon-queue-workers) cause he was using Artisan CLI and I'm using `supervisor`.

Comment: You could put the app down then deploy?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't, cause I want to deploy as frequently an I can AND I have many people working with UI. @ka_lin

Comment: Depends on your deployment strategy, you could (on deploy) make a directory (on the same level as your app) run the deploy and make a symlink to point to the current version (though a artisan down and up when switching would be needed for data integrity)

Comment: @ka_lin not in docker :(

Deployer doesn't support docker. Yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`autorestart=true` in `supervisor` + `php artisan queue:restart` solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is a built-in feature for this:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

> This command will instruct all queue workers to gracefully "die" after they finish processing their current job so that no existing jobs are lost. Since the queue workers will die when the queue:restart command is executed, you should be running a process manager such as Supervisor to automatically restart the queue workers.

Answer (score 0):

Supervisord has an [XML-RPC Api](http://supervisord.org/api.html) which you could use from your php code. I sugesst you use [Zend's XML-RPC Client](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-xmlrpc/client/)