# Laravel Restart specific queue

Tags: php, laravel

Is there away to restart a specific queue in laravel. I know you can restart the all the queue by running `php artisan queue:restart`, but how to run something like `php artisan queue:restart --queue='MyEmailsQueue'`. Better even to restart the queue by hitting an endpoint like `Artisan::queue('send-emails') restart`

Comment: There is no built-in command for it.

Comment: Is there something you can suggest or recommend to handle this?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060526/laravel-artisan-cli-safely-stop-daemon-queue-workers

Comment: No that’s not how queues work. Unless you intentionally split each queue in a separate process. From there you can restart a process that represents a queue, or a queue group (this includes a tremendous amount of possible complications). But by default, all queues are provided by the same process.